# Highcharts Sparkline in reactjs without Jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, sparklines

The sample code given for **Highcharts Sparkline** uses jquery.(https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline)

But I should **not use jquery** in my project. I wrote a code in react js to accept the data dynamically from another file and render the table.I have no idea how to implement the sparkline chart **without using jquery** references.

Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Can you explain which part of the code is the problem to you? All the jquery functions are replaceable with the native js functions.

Comment: The part where the data is fetched from td attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the demo to React. It is available on github [here](https://github.com/morganfree/react-highcharts-sparkline). You can also see it live in React sandbox - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8no9wgg2).

So I created two components:

- `SparkLine` which builds a chart from the given options
- `SparkLineTable` which takes the tables rows (children) and transform them to a chart if they have `data-sparkline` attribute

So app as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import SparkLineTable from './components/SparkLineTable.jsx';

const App = () =>
  <SparkLineTable>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Income</th>
        <th>Income per quarter</th>
        <th>Costs</th>
        <th>Costs per quarter</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>Result per quarter</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody-sparkline">
      <tr>
        <th>Alabama</th>
        <td>254</td>
        <td data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66 " />
        <td>296</td>
        <td data-sparkline="68, 52, 80, 96 " />
        <td>-42</td>
        <td data-sparkline="3, 26, -41, -30 ; column" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </SparkLineTable>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

gives the output like this:

[image: highcharts-sparkline-react]

The part which transforms `<td>` to `<SparkLine />`:

```
toSparkLine(children) {
  let header

  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child

    if (child.type === 'th') header = child.props.children

    if (child.props['data-sparkline']) {
      return this.sparkLine(child, header)
    }

    if (child.props.children) {
      child = React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: this.toSparkLine(child.props.children)
      })
    }

    return child
  })
}

sparkLine(element, header) {
  const dataAttr = element.props['data-sparkline'].split('; ')

  const data = dataAttr[0].split(', ').map(Number)
  const options = {
    series: [{
      data,
      pointStart: 1
    }],

    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: `<span style="font-sze:10px">${header}, Q{point.x}: </span><br/>`,
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
    },
    chart: {
      type: dataAttr[1] || 'area'
    }
  }

  return <SparkLine options={options} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for your scenario is to use REACT_SPARKLINES instead of highcharts which is too easy to implement.

https://github.com/borisyankov/react-sparklines

view this link and rock